# Default authorization policy for all ABP endpoints

Tags: c#, authorization, abp

According to [authorization document](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization) in abp.io framework I need to use AuthorizeAttribute for application service or its methods. For asp.net core authorization pipeline I can use [RequireAuthorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authorizationendpointconventionbuilderextensions.requireauthorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) extension method to protect all methods of all controllers instead of using AuthorizeAttribute. How can I achieve this behaviour in abp.io?